# What are possible counters to this Pokémon lineup?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

I recently saw a battle video that helped me come with this potential lineup for Double Battles:

- Durant

  - Hidden Ability (Truant)
  - Entrainment
- Shedinja

  - Focus Sash
  - Mimic
- Spiritomb

  - Leftovers
  - Toxic
  - Will-O-Wisp
- Any Pokémon with Heal Bell or a related attack

The idea is to lead with Durant and Shedinja, have Durant use Entrainment to pass its Trunt ability to an opponent, then have Shedinja use Mimic to learn Entrainment.

On turn two, switch out Durant for Spiritomb and have Shedinja use Entrainment on it to pass it Wonder Guard.

Should Spritomb be hit with Poison/Burn, the Heal Bell can fix it, and it can counterattack with its own status-inflicting moves.

---

So what dangers should this team look out for? Obviously if Shedinja is taken out before it can use Entrainment the whole thing falls apart (faster opponents, Rock Slide/Heat Wave combo...) but usually the risk of this happening can be predicted just by looking at the opponent's team on the preview.

Aside from that, I think the only real risk is the Heal Bell user being KO'd. Are there any other risks I haven't seen here?

Comment: Have you checked the Smogon forums?  They're really into comp. battling; you try it out!

Comment: @Retrosaur My only concern with suggesting Smogon is that their primary focus is on single battles - I don't know that they have much (if any) coverage or commentary on Double Battle strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary threat to this team looks like it would be something with automatic Hail or Sandstorm - any major threat with Sand Stream (Tyranitar or Hippowdon) or Snow Warning (Abomasnow) will wreck the gimmick entirely, as Shedinja has precisely one HP, Wonder Guard doesn't block Weather damage, and Focus Sash will not activate against Weather damage either. To mitigate this, you may wish to have your Cleric carrying a weather move of its own - Vaporeon could fit the bill, with Heal Bell, Wish, and Rain Dance. Hydration can be used to keep it even more safe. You'll also need Durant to carry abilities that can check these threats, even when they've become Truant.

Comment: Interesting. I've always wanted to use a Vaporeon in a team but never could find a good use for it. I'll definitely give this a try. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Kolink You're quite welcome. Vaporeon is also quite bulky, so between Wish and Hydration, she should be ridiculously hard to dislodge, and you already know what a Wondertomb is capable of. :)